# Azure Ad b2c: Get email in Claims after successfully Signin in azure ad b2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using starter pack of custom polices with **SocialAndLocalAccounts** pack.

It is working fine for me.

But I am facing one issue.I need to get email as claim after successfully login.
I am getting email as claim, once user has been been signed-up and redirects back immediately to application.

but I am not getting it when a user simply signs-in.

How can I get that?
where do I need to write an **Output** Claim to get the value of email in claim?

Kindly help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following describes how you can save, load, and then issue the **otherMails** claim as **emails** from the sign-up/sign-in and password reset policies.

When writing a local account: You must create the **otherMails** claim from the **email** claim using the **CreateOtherMailsFromEmail** claims transformation and then persist the **otherMails** claim in the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  ...
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateOtherMailsFromEmail" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    ...
  </InputClaims>
  <PersistedClaims>
    ...
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
  </PersistedClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    ...
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
  </OutputClaims>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

You must then pass the **otherMails** claim out from the **LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail** technical profile that is invoked to register a local account:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
    ...
    <OutputClaims>
        ...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

When writing a social account: The **otherMails** claim is already created from the **email** claim and then persisted in the **AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId** technical profile.

You must then pass the **otherMails** claim out from the **SelfAsserted-Social** technical profile that is invoked to register a social account:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">
    ...
    <OutputClaims>
        ...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

When reading a local or social account: The **otherMails** claim is already read in the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId**, **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress**, and **AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId** technical profiles.

You must then pass the **otherMails** claim out from the **LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress** technical profile that is invoked to recover a local password:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
    ...
    <OutputClaims>
        ...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

To issue the **otherMails** claim as **emails** from the sign-up/sign-in and password reset policies: You must add the **otherMails** claim as `<OutputClaim />` to the relying party policies:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
    ...
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
        <OutputClaims>
            ...
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: you are just awesome.Thanks

Comment: I faced the same issue as the OP. But, reading this reply, I'm just like **_WTF?_**... even if maybe leading to success, this is my understanding of configuration hell and a totally screwed up "Framework". (Rant over)

Comment: @chris-pagett How can we get email  if we are using signup and signing using username with custom policy?

Answer (score 13):

For Chris Padgett's answer, you can add other emails (Alternate email) into the claim.

If you just want to add email claim from the SignIn name into the token, you can just take following steps:

1. Open your `SignUporSignIn.xml` file
2. Replace `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />` with `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />`
3. Save this SignUporSignIn.xml file and upload it to Azure AD B2C to overwrite the policy.
4. Run the SignUporSignIn policy to test it.
   Here is my test result, you can see the email claim in the token:
   [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's nice, but it doesn't work for a password reset policy.  I was finally able to get a reset policy working as well by adding the same OutputClaim you mention, but also adding OrchestrationStep 3 from UserJourney SignUpOrSignIn to the PasswordReset UserJourney in TrustFrameworkBase.xml.

Answer (score 5):

Another option that is working for me was to extend `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` so that it copies the `signInNames.emailAddress` claim into `email`. That brought sign-in into alignment with our other journeys/sub-journeys for integrated sign-up, password reset, and social log-in -- which each populate `email` during first log-in/sign-up.

All I needed to do was add this to `TrustFrameworkExtension.xml` (under `<ClaimsProviders>`):

```xml
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>

      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim 
              ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"
              PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress"
            />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: this is a better answer as it adds the email for all journeys... not just the SignUpSignIn. Additionally if you are combining Social/AAD login w/Local Accounts your SignUpSignIn wont contain multiple entries for 'email' claim (which is confusing because only 1 will be populated based on the SignIn method)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider local accounts and social account differently for email output since B2C store these email related attributes differently. Here is the solution I had:

1.For local account add  into AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId TP, for example:

```
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

2. For social accounts, add one claimstransformation TP for extra claims exchange userjourney steps to bring email to claims bag.

For example:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateEmailFromOtherMails" TransformationMethod="GetSingleItemFromStringCollection"> <InputClaims> <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" TransformationClaimType="collection" /> </InputClaims> <OutputClaims>
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="extractedItem" /> </OutputClaims </ClaimsTransformation>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#example-of-getsingleitemfromstringcollection