# Output claims does not contain email after login in Azure AD B2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I am using azure ad b2c custom policies for user signIn and signUp.
I am trying to get user's email as part of the output claims, unfortunately unable to get email in output claims.
I am using SignUpOrSignIn user journey in template policy

**TrustFrameworkBase.xml**

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Your password is incorrect</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
        <!-- Policy Engine Clients -->
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
     <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid email</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Optional claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
   <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />  
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />  
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <!--gscott added -->
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

**Template policy**

```
<RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
<TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName"/>

        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I have tried to find all the other answered questions, but was not able succeed.
Any direction and help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352605/azure-ad-b2c-get-email-in-claims-after-successfully-signin-in-azure-ad-b2c.

Comment: I tried to follow the link,unfortunately i ended in a error .When hit run now in azure, it tries to open the SignIn screen but the status from the server is canceled.