# Accessing email when accessing Azure B2C Identity (with member user)

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Identity Server 4 and using the following scopes, however I am unable to access the claim email.

```
              .AddOpenIdConnect("AzureB2C", "External Users AD_B2C",
                          options =>
                          {
                              options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                              options.Authority = appConfig.AzureB2C.Authority;
                              options.ClientId = appConfig.AzureB2C.ClientId;
                              options.ClientSecret = appConfig.AzureB2C.Secret;
                              options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                              options.Scope.Add("openid");
                              options.Scope.Add("email");
                              options.Scope.Add("profile");[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The openid-configuration does mention emails as supported but I cannot get this claim either

"claims_supported": [
"name",
"emails",
"given_name",
"idp",
"family_name",
"oid",
"sub",
"idp_access_token",
"tfp",
"iss",
"iat",
"exp",
"aud",
"acr",
"nonce",
"auth_time"
]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to [add claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352605/azure-ad-b2c-get-email-in-claims-after-successfully-signin-in-azure-ad-b2c) shows you how to get email in Claims after successfully Signin in azure ad b2c.

**Note** about email claim:

If the user authenticates with a social identity provider, the email address is stored in the **otherMails** property. If a local account is based on a user name, then the email address is stored in a strong authentication detail property. If a local account is based on an email address, then the email address is stored in the **signInNames** property.

Only the otherMails and signInNames properties are exposed through the Microsoft Graph API. The email address in the strong authentication detail property is not available.

---

If you want to get emails in the id_token claims, the `Email Addresses` must be selected in the portal(Navigate to userFlow-> Application claims). You could **Run user flow** to test it.

[image]